# Why does Elastic Beanstalk node in AWS Toolkit in Eclipse not show my environments?

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-toolkit

I'm using the latest Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0), Build id: 20190314-1200, with Java 12.0.1 and AWS Toolkit v2.

I am following this documentation in the first topic, titled "Changing Environment Configuration Settings".

[Changing Environment Configuration Settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.managingappenv.html)

It tells me to double-click the Elastic Beanstalk node in AWS Explorer to see the environments in Elastic Beanstalk. However, when I do that, I don't see any of my environment that's up and running in Elastic Beanstalk.

[image]

Where do I need to go in Eclipse check out the problem? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up your AWS account in Eclipse (Eclipse->Preferences->AWS Toolkit)